# How can I store the values ​of the json or request in a variable without using future builder or list builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use the information I get from the json or request and be able to use it in a useraccountheader drawer but **WITHOUT**, using a list builder or future builder.

I usually use a future builder and display the information from the database.

I want to get the json or request information and store it in a variable or use it directly in a text widget.

It is also to have loaded user information.
In the infoinitialuser2 list, the values ​​of the json or request are stored and I show them in the list builder or future builder, but as I just mentioned, I don't want to do it that way.

code::

```
Class State<NombreCabeceraDrawer> extends StatefulWidget{return nombrecabeceradrawer()}

class nombrecabeceradrawer extends State<NombreCabeceraDrawer> {

verride
  void initState() {
    cabeceradrawerservices.MostrarInfoInicialUser().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        info.addAll(value);
      });
    } );
  
    
   
    super.initState();
  }

  UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                              accountName: Text("here i want to show the value of the json or request"),
                            accountEmai: Text("here i want to show the value of the json or request too")
                        
                          ),

}
-------------------

class InfoUsuarioInicialServices{

  Future  MostrarInfoInicialUser() async{
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Charset':'utf-8'
    };

    var Url= Uri.parse("http://");
    final response = await http.get((Url),headers: headers);
    print(response.body);
    return productInfoUsuarioInicialromJson(response.body);
  }

}
---------------------
List  productInfoUsuarioInicialromJson(String str) => List<InfoInicialUserModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => InfoInicialUserModel.fromJson(x)));// con esto hago el get

class InfoInicialUserModel{

  String UsuarioPk;
  String FotoUsuario;
  String CorreoUsuario;
  String NombreUsuario;

  InfoInicialUserModel({this.UsuarioPk,this.FotoUsuario,this.NombreUsuario,this.CorreoUsuario});

  factory InfoInicialUserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return InfoInicialUserModel(
        UsuarioPk: parsedJson['Usuari'],
        FotoUsuario:parsedJson['image'],
        NombreUsuario: parsedJson['Usuario_A'],
        CorreoUsuario:parsedJson['Usuario_C']
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You already inserted jsondata into the variables in the class InfoInicialUserMode. So now you should be able to access it immediately: accountName: InfoInicialUserMode.UsuarioPk

Comment: A more simplistic way: var text1; var jsonData = json.decode(response.body); setState(() => text1 = jsonData['Usuari]'});

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
Future GetMostrarInfoInicialUser() async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Charset': 'utf-8'
    };

    var Url = Uri.parse("http://");
    final response = await http.get((Url), headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (jsonData == "Error") {
      } else {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            accountEmail = jsonData['accountEmail'];
            accountName = jsonData['accountName'];
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    GetMostrarInfoInicialUser();
  }
```